# CP210x Driver on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am trying to communicate with a ESP8266 NodeMCU board plugged into my USB port.

I beleive it should show up as /dev/ttyUSB0 per other posts but ttyUSB0 does not show up in /dev

from lsusb i can see the board:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:2110 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:1010 Dell Computer Corp. USB 2.0 Hub [MTT]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 10c4:ea60 Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge
```

The CP210x driver is installed:

```
$ dpkg -L linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-33-generic | grep cp210x
/lib/modules/5.4.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/cp210x.ko
```

but when run the following I get the following errors:

```
$ sudo modprobe cp210x
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'cp210x': Exec format error
```

or

```
$ sudo modprobe cp210x.ko
modprobe: FATAL: Module cp210x.ko not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-33-generic
```

When I run lsmod, cp210x does not show up at all.

Also when viewing the /dev directory there are a large numbers of tty:

```
crw-rw----   1 root     4,  64 Jun  5 22:40 ttyS0
crw-rw----   1 root     4,  65 Jun  5 21:47 ttyS1
crw-rw----   1 root     4,  74 Jun  5 21:47 ttyS10
crw-rw----   1 root     4,  75 Jun  5 21:47 ttyS11
crw-rw----   1 root     4,  76 Jun  5 21:47 ttyS12
crw-rw----   1 root     4,  77 Jun  5 21:47 ttyS13
crw-rw----   1 root     4,  78 Jun  5 21:47 ttyS14
crw-rw----   1 root     4,  79 Jun  5 21:47 ttyS15
crw-rw----   1 root     4,  80 Jun  5 21:47 ttyS16
crw-rw----   1 root     4,  81 Jun  5 21:47 ttyS17
crw-rw----   1 root     4,  82 Jun  5 21:47 ttyS18
crw-rw----   1 root     4,  83 Jun  5 21:47 ttyS19
crw-rw----   1 root     4,  66 Jun  5 21:47 ttyS2
```

But how do I know which is linked to:

```
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 10c4:ea60 Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge
```

Comment: Such modules are usually precompiled in kernel. There is no need to compile and/or load them manually. They may appear as `/dev/ttyACM0` too.

Comment: I can find the device /dev/ttyUSB0, but can not connected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your USB cable, I had the same problem and it was on my cable.